# Error setting fullscreen property of cv2 window

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make a window created with opencv2 fullscreen. I've been through other solutions posted here and elsewhere and always end up with an error.

First I'm making the namedWindow with:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Target", cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_NORMAL)
```

then:

```
cv2.setWindowProperty("Target", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN'
```

I've tried using:

```
cv2.CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN
```

instead, as per the docs, with same error.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong!?
If it's something that's impossible- can anyone offer another suggestion for how to draw a cv2 image to a fullscreen window (with no GUI/toolbars showing)? Frankly I'd be happy with anything as long as it's not too processor intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using pygame's windows and fullscreen mode and skipping openCV entirely.

Answer (score 3):

The `cv2` module constants are sometimes behind the C++ version, to say the least, especially if you have OpenCV Python bindings installed from old packages (like in an older Ubuntu LTS release ;).

But the fact that the constants are not exported to Python does not mean, that they don't work like they should.

I have at hand:

```
>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.8'
```

Here there's no `cv2.CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN`, but:

```
>> cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN
0
```

(the newer `cv2` implementations don't prefix many flags with `CV_`)

I didn't know that the value for the property needs to be taken from the older `cv2.cv` module (it's the module with the old Python bindings):

```
>> cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN
1
```

Yes, it's simply `1`.

So this is simple - to use fullscreen:

- Create the windows with `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` flag
- To go fullscreen:

  `cv2.setWindowProperty('Target', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, 1)`
- or if you miss cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN:

  `cv2.setWindowProperty('Target', 0, 1)`
- To exit fullscreen:

  `cv2.setWindowProperty('Target', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, 0)`
- or:

  `cv2.setWindowProperty('Target', 0, 0)`

Even when the bindings are missing these flags, the underlying C++ implementation works.